# Inserting upload script into existing form page does not process upload?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a file upload script which works great when opened from the calling page via window.open(). However, I'm trying to avoid the popup window and load the script into the calling page itself (via jQuery.load()).

However, although everything appears to work fine, the file does not actually get transferred. The calling page is itself a form. Could that cause the problem?

```
<form id="myParentPage">

    <div id="myUploadPlaceholder"></div>

    <input type="button" id="loadScript" value="Test" />


    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
        {
        $('#loadScript').click(function() {
            $('#myUploadPlaceholder').load('myUploadScript.php?action=test' );
        });
    });
    </script>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a hidden iframe instead:

```
<iframe id="myUploadPlaceholder" src="_blank"></iframe>

<input type="button" id="loadScript" value="Test" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $('#loadScript').click(function() {
        $('#myUploadPlaceholder').attr('src','myUploadScript.php?action=test');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: +1 This does work. Are there any advantages with this method over using window.open?